# How to access values from a configuration file stored in subdirectory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, app-config, subdirectory

Accessing config values at run-time in Laravel 4 is done using its Config class:

```
Config::get('app.timezone');
```

To organize the config files, I'd like to put them into different sub-directories.

**For example:**

- `/config/users/`  ->  *for user specific configuration*
- `/config/auth/`    ->  *authentication related*
- and so on...

I read [an elder Tutorial](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/configuration) (Laravel v3) from Dayle Rees him stating that it's possible with the following:

```
$option = Config::get('ourconfig.sub.directory.size');
```

Tried it out with no luck. According to [Jason Lewis](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=9485#p9485) it was never supported.

Then I've had a look at the Laravel 4 API and found [load()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Config.FileLoader.html#48-91) and [getRequire()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Config.FileLoader.html#234-243) (more related functions can be found [here](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Config.Repository.html)).

However, I couldn't find a way to grab sub-dir config values in L4.

So,

1. Is this possible with Laravel 4?
2. …and, if so, how?

Comment: @TryingTobemyself Sweet. That works. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It was just unclear in the docs and api... Also Laravel 4 is pretty new...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution to your problem that works for me is:

```
Config::get('subdir/file.key');
```

Did you try this one yet or are you looking for more complex method?

Comment: Didn't try that one before. "Why seek far afield when the good is close by?" - that's the motto that reflects my first thought on your answer :-)

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5 and above you have to use like this Config::get('subdir.file.key'); or if you have sub array inside your return statement Config::get('subdir.subarray.file.key'); The same syntax for nested arrays and subdirectories. 
For this example this config returns value from subdir -> subarray-> file (also array) -> key